# echo javascript function in php - echoing in console, but not running javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, function, echo

I am trying to run a javascript function once a user click on a button. I am echoing the script, but nothing is happening.

```
button code in .php file:
case 'create':
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">clearform();</script>';
break;

Javascript file:
function clearform()
{
    document.getElementById("serviceMileage").value="";  
}

It only displays this in the console:
<script type="text/javascript">clearform();</script>
```

I want to clear an input field once a user clicks on the button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: Just add `clearform();` to an `onclick` attribute on your button. `<button onclick="clearform();">Button</button>` - You are going to have a hard time making PHP run a JavaScript function on your page.

Comment: I know I can do that, but I first want to execute more code in the button code and once a condition is met, I want to clear the input field

Comment: How do you submit the form? It's ajax or regular form submit?

Comment: regular form submit <form method="post" onsubmit="return actionClick('create')" id="createServiceReportForm">

Comment: How are you echoing the script onclick? Ajax call?

Comment: Yes sorry ajax call, my bad

Comment: It's better to return some value from the backend, like `{"error":"1"}`. Then in the function where you process the return you can check `if (data.error ==1) clearform();`

Comment: Okay thanks will add that. Where do you think is my problem?

Comment: Are you writing the response back to the page after it comes back from ajax?

Comment: Sorry I am new to this. Can you please give me more detail to your question?

Comment: Well, when you receive the response back from your php, it's essentially passive data until you do something with it. If you took the `<script type="text/javascript">clearform();</script>` from the php and put it back into your current page, it likely would work. So you would use something like `document.getElementById('confirmation').innerHTML = response;` and it would place that script into an empty `div` like `<div id="confirmation"></div>` which would already be on your page somewhere.

Comment: @Rasclatt Thank you. Could you maybe show me how to this in my code. I would really appreciate it

Comment: You don't have enough code to know what you are actually doing that is not working. I would need to see the relevant ajax and html.